# Manifest is not well-formed

Tags: android, xml, manifest

I've got a problem with my manifest, someone could help? 
It shows 'Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.  AndroidManifest.xml /WrotaDziekanatu    line 1  Android XML Format Problem'

```
<<<<<<< Original
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.wrotadziekanatu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.DisplayAuthorActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_author" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity"/>     
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.Otwarty"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_otwarty" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity"/>     
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.Zamkniety"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_zamkniety" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity"/>     
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.Przerwa"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_przerwa" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity"/>     
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.Wewnetrzny"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_wewnetrzny" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.wrotadziekanatu.MainActivity"/>     
    </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Remove this from manifest --><<<<<<< Original

Comment: i guess u r doing git operation so <<<<<<<<same into picture

Comment: wow, that was a problem. thanks!

Comment: :) u should solve this isssue self.....better luck next time

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<<<<<<< Original`.